# How to get Server Fingerprint Details of a server

Tags: web-services, security

I want to know Details of Fingerprint of a server. Here is a sample Picture. Representation format is not a fact. I just Need Values.

Is there any online or desktop tool to get this ?

[image]

Comment: httprint http://www.net-square.com/httprint.html

Comment: that picture just shows the request and response headers. is that what you want?

Comment: @guest, i have to make a pentest report of a server. this picture is some of many. I think that those picture was taken from a screen shot of some software or online tool that analysis a web server. I Need something like this.
FYI: I have been through OpenVas, Retina, MBSA, Nexpose.